# How to integrate a web server within an android app?

Tags: android, webserver

I need server an web into my app to share the files generated. I was been looking for in many sites and I didn't find nothing.

any idea? Advices, web sites, libraries...

Comment: As I have written elsewhere, I sincerely hope that this is for personal use only, and that you are not seriously considering putting a Web server -- with an open, unprotected server socket -- on lots of mobile devices. If you are, I hope you have a well-financed legal defense fund.

Comment: Only work when the user activates it, and only in local network.

Answer (score 0):

If you are consuming a soap webservice, see [ksoap](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/), for json-rpc see [this wiki](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/implementations)

Comment: You don't misunderstood me, I don't need information about Web services, I need information about web servers in Android.

Comment: Any solution in java is also a solution in adroid, the ksoap2 should be suficient for you if you use soap and the java json-rpc solutions on the wiki for RPC. Which websevice you are trying to connect?